# Dictionary with dynamic entries in StringTemplate

Tags: stringtemplate, stringtemplate-4

I'm using StringTemplate 4.0.8 with Java.

In the [StringTemplate-4 documentation](https://github.com/antlr/stringtemplate4/blob/master/doc/groups.md#dictionaries), it says that

> Dictionary strings can also be templates that can refer to attributes
>   that will become visible via dynamic scoping of attributes once the
>   dictionary value has been embedded within a template.

How exactly do I do that? Can I do something like this:

```
output(input) ::= "The output is: <aDicitionary.input>"

aDictionary ::= [
    "someKey":"someValue",
    "someOtherKey":"someOtherValue",
    "aCertainKey": **HERE** i want the value to be <input>,
    default:"doesnt matter"
]
```

So that `output("someKey")` results in `The output is: someValue`
and `output(aCertainKey)` results in "The output is: aCertainKey". If so, how exactly would the syntax look like?

I know that I could achieve the same by just not passing an input in one case and then checking if I have an input or not. But that would result in a lot of if's on the Java side which I

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use a dynamic dictionary entry:

```
output(input) ::= <%The output is: <aDicitionary.(input)>%>
```

Use no quotes around the template and put `input` in parentheses to evaluate it.

To have dynamic content in a dictionary (the subject of the cited block):

```
aDictionary ::= [
  "someKey":"someValue",
  "someOtherKey":"someOtherValue",
  "aCertainKey": {input from scope <inputFromScope>},
  default:"doesnt matter"
]
```

Use braces around the keys and variable (or template) references inside. Now calling

```
<output(input="aCertainKey", inputFromScope="myInput")>
```

will output

```
The output is: input from scope myInput
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Thanks a lot! :-)